# Page redirect on an IIS server

Tags: redirect, iis

Sorry if I'm totally confused and barking up the wrong tree here!

I know that on an Apache server I can set up a .htaccess file and use Redirect to, well, redirect a specific url to a specific new url

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html /newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Is there a similar function/ability for IIS servers?  I don't know a huge amount about the setup other than IIS & asp.net, but am trying to point the IT guys in the right direction, ie: not using a meta refresh/redirect!!   I can find out more info if required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this steps:

1) Install IIS URL rewrite module to your server if not installed https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

2) In web.config of your website add this rule:

```
<rule name="redirect1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="olddirectory/oldfile.html" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/newdirectory/newfile.html" />
</rule>
```

Then you will receive redirect from  `/olddirectory/oldfile.html` to `/newdirectory/newfile.html`